# how to check std::is_base_of<> on (*this)

Tags: c++, gcc, type-traits, static-assert, protothread

For certain task, I didn't manage to get away without macro. Now I'd like to add at least some protection from misuse.

I'd like to `static_assert` that MYMACRO() is used

1. in a subclass of Base class,...
2. ...namely, in `run()` method

A naive approach fails:

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, typeid(*this)>::value, "Use MYMACRO() only in subclass of Base.");
//                                  =============
//       SubOne would work, but not typeid(*this)
//
static_assert(__func__ == "run", "Use MYMACRO() only in run() method.");
//            ========
//       not a constexpr?
//
```

To reproduce:

```
#ifndef __GNUG__
#error "Needs GCC C++"
#endif

#define MYMACRO() \
{\
    do { \
    /*> > > want static_assert'ions here < < <*/\
    /*here comes stuff I coudn't put into an [inline] function,*/ \
    /*because it contains GCC Labels-as-Values and */ \
    /*conditional return;*/ \
    } while(false);\
}

class Base {
public:
    virtual int run() = 0;
};

class SubOne : Base {
public:
    int run() override {
        // ...
        MYMACRO();
        // ...
    };
};

class SubTwo : Base {
public:
    int run() override {
        // ...
        MYMACRO();
        // ...
    };
};

int main(void) 
{
    SubOne sub1;
    SubTwo sub2;
    //a little embedded app
    while (true) {
        sub1.run();
        sub2.run();
    }
}
```

Anticipating possible questions:
What is it for? - http://dunkels.com/adam/dunkels06protothreads.pdf
Labels as values: - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html
Why not "proper" [RTOS](https://freertos.org/) with context switching? - I expect the above solution to simplify unit testing under native architecture, side-stepping the need for [native (POSIX) port](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/1.12.0/boards/posix/native_posix/doc/board.html) or [QEMU](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/plus/debug-tools/qemu.html)/[renode](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/plus/debug-tools/renode.html) or [target board](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/tutorials/ststm32/stm32cube_debugging_unit_testing.html#tutorial-stm32cube-debugging-unit-testing). (Not for all, but for many tests)

Comment: The type of an expression is obtained with `decltype`, not `typeid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typeid` is the wrong tool here, because it returns a referene to a `type_info` instance, which is not the type of `*this` but only contains information on the type.

You can use `decltype`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


struct base {};

struct foo : base {
    foo() {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<base,std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type>::value);
    }
};

struct foo_fail {
    foo_fail() {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<base,std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type>::value);
    }
};
```

Compiler output:

```
prog.cc: In constructor 'foo_fail::foo_fail()':
prog.cc:15:23: error: static assertion failed
         static_assert(std::is_base_of<base,std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type>::value);
                       ^~~
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `typeid(*this)` with `std::decay_t<decltype(*this)>`.

And, to compare strings at compile time, use `std::string_view`:

```
static_assert(std::string_view(__func__) == "main", "Use MYMACRO() only in run() method.");
```